# Confusion about StateT, State and MonadState

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I'm utterly confused between

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT {runStateT :: s -> m (a, s)}
```

and

```
type State s = StateT s Identity
```

and

```
class Monad m => MonadState s m | m -> s
```

Comment: What is your exact question? What type of goals you're trying to accomplish? Where your confusion comes from? You don't know what is `newtype`, `type` and `class`? If you just don't understand those structures then just read some Haskell tutorials. StackOverflow is for specific questions.

Comment: And the question is...? :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Once upon a time, there was a `State` type:

```
-- Not the current definition.
newtype State s a = State {runState :: s -> (a, s)}
```

`State s a` values are, in essence, functions that take a state and produce a result and an updated state. Suitable `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad` instances make it possible to compose such functions in a more convenient manner, by making the tuple shuffling need to handle the `(a, s)` output implicit. With the help of a handful basic of operations that manipulate the state...

```
get = State $ \s -> (s, s)
put s = State $ \_ -> ((), s)
```

... it is possible to avoid any mention of the underlying `s -> (a, s)` type, and write code that *feels* stateful.

`StateT s` is a monad transformer patterned after `State s`:

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT {runStateT :: s -> m (a, s)}
```

This transformer adds the state processing capabilities described above atop a base monad, `m`. It comes with `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad` instances, as well as versions of `get` and `put`.

If `m`, the base monad, in `StateT s m` is `Identity`, the dummy functor...

```
newtype Identity a = Identity {runIdentity :: a}
```

... we get something equivalent to plain old `State s`. That being so, *transformers* defines `State` as a synonym...

```
type State s = StateT s Identity
```

... rather than as a separate type.

As for `MonadState`, it caters to two different needs. Firstly, we can use the monad transformers machinery to have `StateT s m` as a base monad for some other transformer in a stack of transformers (arbitrary example: `MaybeT (StateT Int IO)`). In that case, though, `lift` from `MonadTrans` becomes necessary to use `get` and `put`. One way of using the operations directly in such cases is through `MonadState`: it provides them as methods...

```
-- Abridged class definition.
class Monad m => MonadState s m | m -> s where
    get :: m s
    put :: s -> m ()
    state :: (s -> (a, s)) -> m a
```

... so that we can have instances for any combination of transformers involving `StateT` that we are interested in.

```
instance Monad m => MonadState s (StateT s m) where -- etc.
instance MonadState s m => MonadState s (MaybeT m) where -- etc.
-- And so forth
```

Secondly, if we want to have a state monad with an implementation different than the one in *transformers*, we can make it an instance of `MonadState`, so that we keep the same basic operations and, as long as we write type signatures in terms of `MonadState`, have it easier to change implementations if need be.

Comment: Although profusely upvoted, this answer suffers from the same problem I find in _all_ the Haskell books. It shows the instances, unnecessarily, because the same could be found in the documentation, but no usage or examples. It is not particularly exhilarating to know something called `MonadState` exists, unless one knows what the heck it is used for and how.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar This answer is not a tutorial, indeed, but just a modestly scoped reply aimed at helping readers in the situation of the question author -- someone initially acquainted with `StateT` but finding it hard to keep those three similarly-named things apart. Off the top of my head, you might appreciate the state monad chapter in the Wikibook, which has a more tutorial-like flavour: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/State

Answer (score 9):

`State` is for your normal state monad.  This is the simplest of the three.  (In some older tutorials, you may see use of the `State` constructor, but this has been replaced with the `state` function, because `State s` is now a type alias for `StateT s Identity`.)

`StateT` is the monad transformer for the `State` monad.  It adds a layer of generality by allowing you to put an arbitrary monad inside the state.  This is useful for simple parsers, which could use e.g. `StateT [Token] Maybe Result` to represent the parsing as a stateful operation that could fail.

`MonadState` generalizes the situation even farther.  There is an instance `Monad m => MonadState s (StateT s m)`, but there are also instances, like one that allows you to perform stateful operations on monad transformers of `StateT`.  All basic state functions (`get`, `set`, `modify`, etc.) can be used with an instance of `MonadState`.